# Swift ios odd space when hiding navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, layout

When I hide my navigation bar I end up with some space under it, it looks like the status bar is twice as big as it should be.

[image]

In the image the red line is just touching where the statusbar/navigation bar ends.

My VC is contains a scroll view that is spaced 0 to the edges and spaced 0 to the top layout guide.

Why is the navigation bar not hiding completly? I thought that if you hide the navigation bar you would end up with a 20px statusbar showing only.

I could space my scrollview to be +20 from the top view but that seems a bit hacky.

Comment: Have you tried it on a device, rather than in the simulator? I only ask because I've personally seen differences between preview, simulator and actual device with things like this.

Answer (score -1):

Look for `Extended Edges` in attribute inspector of the view controller and uncheck `Under Top Bars`.

Comment: elaborate your answer